# I am going to start with GIT (at work) - should I use GUIs, GUIs/terminal or only terminal?

Tags: git, content-management-system, repository

I am new got GIT and we are going to start using it at work (migrating from SVN used with Eclipse).

My question is:

**In the long run, what is smarter? Learn using GIT via multiple GUI applications, using multiple GUI applications and the command line or just go full and pure command line?**

Is it worth spending time to be crazy good with GIT only using the command line commands? Can you do everything with command line? The down side is that its just waste of time - and just plain stupid to go command line 2010.

or is it smarter to mix both command line and GUI applications depending on what I should do? The downside of that is you will be crippled without your GUI applications.

Any comments are appreciated.

Update: Visualize branches is of course done with GUI-applications, but for every day work:

- Only GUIs?
- GUIs/command line?
- Only command line?

Comment: Some would argue that using the command-line is much more efficient than using any GUI...

Comment: so you vote pure command line?

Comment: In the end it comes down to what *you* feel more comfortable with. Different people have different preferences... try different things and choose the most appealing ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I use the command line and `gitk`.  The only time I really use `git gui` is when I need to stage only a few files that I've changed, and I've changed a *lot* of other files, such that using `git add -i .` really isn't practical.

Anywho, I'd learn the command line first.  Once you know your way around the Git commands you won't want a fancy GUI at all.  But don't be shy of using `gitk --all` to visualize the repository, especially if you are a visual learner (like me).  Understanding what your commands are doing by seeing their effect on the repository commit graph can be a very powerful learning aid.

Comment: Not necessarily only command line, but *primarily* command line.  I use e.g. `gitk` and `git gui` as described above, but I do not use fancy shell extensions or anything to create commits or push/pull.  I use `gitk` for visualizing history and `git gui` for staging specific files or sections of a file.  Everything else I do on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I would say have a knowledge of how git works at the command line level, since this is what your GUI applications will be invoking.

But then just use a GUI application to increase your productivity and concentrate on things you do know how to work with.

It is always a good idea to understand the technologies you are using before it's too late.

Comment: so in the long run, you say GUI?

Comment: yes, definitely. We are visual creatures, and in order to make quick decisions a UI is always the best method. But when things go wrong, you are going to have to fall back on the command line, so get acquainted with it.

Comment: Remember there is a difference between being awesome at git and using git effectively to increase your coding efficiency .

Answer (score 1):

Imo, if you really want to understand git, you have to learn the commands directly. Depending on the platform, some GUIs have shortcomings anyway as has the plugin for Eclipse.

Still, GUIs are nice to visualize the repository...

Answer (score 0):

Easy visualization of code changes is the most important thing to me. SmartGit does this well, and since v2, they have implemented every feature I have ever needed.

I like the git command line, but haven't needed to use it in years.

SmartGit is a great tool to standardize a company on - it's cross-platform, dead simple, and powerful enough for demanding users.